# equalize the position of the tableView scroll in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a case, there are 2 tableView in 1 UIViewController, how to do when tableView1 is scrolled The position of scroll tableView2 also follows. thank you[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.tableView1 == scrollView {
        self.tableView2.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
    else {
         self.tableView1.contentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried, but there is a notification in the "Will never be executed" function, I use swift 4.2

Comment: can you elaborate ??

Comment: get `scrollViewDidScroll` out of `cellForRowAt` add it at the same scope